# Does CHKDSK have any volume size limitations?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, command-line, external-hard-drive, filesystems

A colleague of mine mentioned he thinks CHKDSK, since it's so old, probably doesn't support very large target volumes. For example, if you wanted to run CHKDSK on a single, super large volume like say, a 16TB external, you would need to turn to alternative tools at that point.

The Microsoft documentation on CHKDSK is pretty vague. Many of the parameter descriptions leave much to be desired, but that's a whole other issue. I'm just wondering, is there a size limit and if so, what is it?

Comment: Know what else is old? NTFS! And Windows! So you’ll be just fine. ;-) Just because a program has existed for a long time doesn’t mean it hasn’t been updated.

Comment: In many years of using Windows, and its MS-DOS predecessor, I have never had a problem using CHKDSK on the largest volume that the version of DOS/Windows it came with can create. If you are using an old CHKDSK with a newer version of DOS/Windows, all bets are off - but the old version of CHKDSK _may_ refuse to run due to the version mismatch.